# Error on launching activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application crashes whenever I launch it! whats wrong with it? I have created a database and I am trying to populate my listview from the database I have created what is the problem with the code and what is the fix for it?

```
02-19 22:02:07.502: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
02-19 22:02:07.502: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.database-1.apk]
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.database-1.apk]
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-19 22:02:07.542: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 11 more
02-19 22:10:47.354: D/AndroidRuntime(364): Shutting down VM
02-19 22:10:47.444: W/dalvikvm(364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.database-2.apk]
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.database-2.apk]
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-19 22:10:47.482: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  ... 11 more
02-19 22:11:10.302: I/Process(364): Sending signal. PID: 364 SIG: 9
02-19 22:11:17.712: D/AndroidRuntime(413): Shutting down VM
02-19 22:11:17.712: W/dalvikvm(413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.database-2.apk]
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.database-2.apk]
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
02-19 22:11:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  ... 11 more
02-19 22:11:19.852: I/Process(413): Sending signal. PID: 413 SIG: 9
```

Activity:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

  public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity {

 private DBHelper mySQLiteAdapter;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

  /*
   *  Create/Open a SQLite database
   *  and fill with dummy content
   *  and close it
   */
  mySQLiteAdapter = new DBHelper(this);
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
  mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("A for Apply");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("B for Boy");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("C for Cat");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("D for Dog");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("E for Egg");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("F for Fish");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("G for Girl");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("H for Hand");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("I for Ice-scream");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("J for Jet");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("K for Kite");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("L for Lamp");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("M for Man");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("N for Nose");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("O for Orange");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("P for Pen");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Q for Queen");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("R for Rain");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("S for Sugar");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("T for Tree");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("U for Umbrella");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("V for Van");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("W for Water");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("X for X'mas");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Y for Yellow");
  mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Z for Zoo");

  mySQLiteAdapter.close();

  /*
   *  Open the same SQLite database
   *  and read all it's content.
   */
  mySQLiteAdapter = new DBHelper(this);
  mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

  Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
  startManagingCursor(cursor);

  String[] from = new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_CONTENT};
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};

  SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
   new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

  listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

}
}

Database Class

```
    package com.example.database;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

      public class DBHelper {

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

    //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
            "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";

    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public DBHelper(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public DBHelper openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public DBHelper openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public long insert(String content){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int deleteAll(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You activity name is "AndroidSQLite" where is MainActivity? can you check AndroidManifest.xml if you are using right activity name?

Comment: You should not perform database operations on main thread move db operation from onCreate to some AsyncTask, otherwise sometime you may get ANR.

Answer (score 0):

you are Tryin to load `MainActivity`

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.database.MainActivity
```

inside your `Manifest.xml` change `MainActivity` to `AndroidSQLite`.

And you must use an `Asynctask` for the Database operations, to avoid `ANR` Dialog.